# Genus of Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory

Determine (with a proof) the genus of the Petersen Graph
[image: Petersen Graph]

I tried drawing it and I think the answer is 1 but I'm not sure how to prove it

Comment: [wikipedia agrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Graphs_of_genus_1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a way to draw the Petersen graph with exactly one crossing, then it suffices to note that it fails to be planar because it [contains a $K_{3,3}$ minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#/media/File:Kuratowski.gif).

Comment: over here, https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/CrossingNumber.shtml, it is noted that the crossing number is 2, and it might actually not be possible to approach the question in this manner. I am wondering if there's any way to do this without explicitly drawing it on a torus.